# Scheme of virtual table

Tags: c, sqlite

I have created a table using a [virtual table module](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html) in the sqlite3 front-end.

I do something like:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE mytable USING mymodule();
```

At which point the module creates a table with--say--3 columns: x, y, and z.

Now when I type:

```
.schema mytable
```

I get this echoed back to me:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE mytable USING mymodule();
```

Is there any way to get it to tell me what columns are available: x, y, and z?

Comment: [PRAGMA table_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) perhaps?

Comment: Yes, that works.  Submit an answer, and I will approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PRAGMA table_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) should work for this. (According to the documentation, it will not display fields marked "hidden", however)